# Duplicate/Clone a shape or object from one fxml to another in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a fxml (shapes.fxml) which contains a different shapes or objects, and i want to load those shapes in another fxml (main.fxml) when i press a button on the main.fxml

I have tried adding the shape (circle) object from the shapes controller into the main controller pane with luck.

```
shapesController shape = new shapesController();
Circle circleCopy = shape.Circle;
Pane.getChildren().add(circleCopy);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after reviewing the basics, i found out that the answer has always been there.

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Shapes.fxml"));

    TitledPane TitledP = (TitledPane) loader.load();

    Pane.getChildren().add(TitledP);
```

For loading a TitledPane from the Shapes.fxml into another fxml's controller Pane.